# Dell inspiron laptop failure due to USB

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

I have a dell inspiron laptop with 8 GB of ram and a 1 TB hard drive.  I recently plugged a usb to Robotic arm interface cable from my laptop to the robot.  My laptop was in sleep mode, and right when I plugged the cable in, the power light switched off.  I let the laptop cool with the battery out for 15 minutes, because it smelled strongly of smoke around the laptop.  now, whenever I switch it on, the air smells like smoke and my laptop starts clicking softly, in addition to not turning on.  The specs are

Tri-Boot:Windows 7 home premium, Backtrack 5 R3, Ubuntu 12.10

8 GB ram

i5 processor

1TB hard drive

15 inch display

this is a fairly new laptop, I bought in in november 2012.  Could you please provide some insight, if not answers into this problem

Comment: What exactly happens when you turn the laptop on? How long does the clicking last?

Comment: You said "whenever I switch it on, the air smells like smoke" and also "in addition to not turning on". Can you add details? Does it go to OS or just sits and smells like smoke with nothing on the screen?

Comment: just smoke smell, no screen activity.  the clicking lasts as long as I hold down the power button

Comment: sounds to me like your robotic arm back fed the USB and killed the power circuit in your machine. Unless you are very skilled with a soldering Iron, can get board layouts for your motherboard and have access to a bunch of components, you are going to probably need to replace the mother board and potentially a whole host of other stuff that got fried. You are most likely better off buying a new machine.

Comment: @pow-lan The machine was $799 usually and I got it for only 499, and I definitely don’t have the money for a new machine

Comment: You might try an RMA. There is usualy one year and I do not think I would go into details as to how it happened. If they ask what happened, shrug your sholders.

Comment: @CarlB RMA?  I have also found that the clicking sound is coming from hear the USB 3.0 comtroller

Comment: @204899 - Return Manufacturerr autherization. a long term for return it to where you got it for a replacment.